# A sum of terms like $(1 + \sin^2x)^{-1}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that 
\[
\frac12\frac1{1+\sin^2 x} + \frac12\frac1{1+\cos^2 x} + \frac12\frac1{1+\sec^2 x}+ \frac12\frac1{1+\csc^2 x} = 1?
\]
Some genius please help me I have been stuck at this for one whole day.

Comment: Please be clearer about the equation.  Some would read  1/2(1+sin^2 x) as $\frac 1{2(1+\sin^2 x)}$ or at least worry that you meant that.  Either  (1+sin^2 x)/2,  (1/2)(1+sin^2 x), or (best) $\LaTeX$.  Trying to solve the problem, I see I had it wrong, so please  1/(2(1+sin^2 x)), or $\LaTeX$

Comment: I would start by getting rid of $\sec$ and $\csc$, replacing them with $\frac 1\cos$ and $\frac 1\sin$.  Then you must have identities for $1+\sin^2 x$ and $1 + \cos^2 x$.  Where does that take you?

Answer (score 6):

Forget about the $2$'s for a while. We have 
$$\frac{1}{1+\sec^2 x}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}}=\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x+1}.$$
Now add $\frac{1}{1+\cos^2 x}$. We get something very simple.  Continue.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that for any $\alpha> 0$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{1+\alpha}+\frac{1}{1+1/\alpha}=\frac{1+1/\alpha+1+\alpha}{(1+\alpha)(1+1/\alpha)}= 1
$$
so 
$$
\frac{1}{1+\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{1+\csc^2x} = 1
$$
wherever $\csc x$ is defined and similarly
$$
\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}+\frac{1}{1+\sec^2x} = 1
$$